# bash shell - Passing string* as command line argument

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to pass string* as argument i.e

```
./myScript.sh searchString*
```

but  it does not like it.

I tried `./myScript.sh 'searchString*'` AND `./myScript.sh "searchString*"`

Can anyone please tell me how can I pass such argument to a bash script?

Comment: Both of those should have worked just fine. How did you test it? Did you forget to quote the usage of `$1` in the script?

Comment: Please include the error in your post.

Comment: what's your error, and how are you parsing the argument within your script?

Comment: how do you know it's not working?

Comment: Probably you are successfully passing the argument into the function, but then failing to quote the expansion of the argument (`$1` instead of `"$1"`) inside the function. But as indicated by other commentators, "it doesn't like it" is not a very good problem description.

Comment: You are correct. Instead of using $1 I used $0. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

using `'searchString*'` will work. Single quotes inhibit shell expansion. This has been true for decades.

From the [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
>   occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Comment: You are correct. Instead of using $1 I used $0. My bad.